# Maven: is it possible to include a test jar in another project's compile scope

Tags: java, maven, junit

Suppose I have two projects A and B, A project has only test cases. Project B depends A, and will use classes in A for source **compile** under `src/main/java`. Is maven able to achieve this? How?

I know this is weird, but this is the situation in my environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you have classes in a test project?

Comment: You can achieve it in maven by marking the jar that has project A as compile dependancy.

Comment: No help, still can not resolve dependencies.

Comment: add your pom lines ...

Comment: If project A only contains testcases, are these sources placed under `src/main/java`? If so, it becomes a "normal" dependency for project B, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [Guide to using attached tests](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html):

Make sure you create those test jars in project A

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And then use them in project B

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for response but i'm afraid you didn't get what I mean, I want use the test jar in project B for **compile** purpose. i.e. use it in src/main/java not src/test/java

Comment: The mechanism is basically the same in both cases. I updated the scope to compile in dependency of project B.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a strange use case. I'd spend some time examining if its really the right project structure.

If you decide if it is the correct project structure its just a dependency in maven. If the classes in Project A are only used for testing in Project B then you may want to set the dependency scope to `test` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test jar like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Using the test artifact by:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I want to use the test jar in project B for source compile purpose(not test case compile). i.e. use it in src/main/java not src/test/java

Comment: If i get you correctly simply use it as dependency. What i don't understand is: `project B for source compile purpose...`?

Comment: I edit my question to make it more clear, could you please take a look?